# Python create variables based on prior time periods

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataset like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
d1={'Participant_ID':['P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2'],
'Brand_Type':['B1','B1','B2','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B1','B2','B1','B1'],
'Date1':['5/6/2010','1/27/2010','4/3/2010','7/11/2010','3/1/2010','6/8/2010',
       '5/6/2010','1/27/2010','4/3/2010','7/11/2010','3/1/2010','6/8/2010']}
d11=pd.DataFrame(d1)
d11['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(d11['Date1'])
#converting to date var explicitly to avoid any issues and sorting the data by Participant ID and Date
d111=d11.sort_values(by=['Participant_ID','Date2'])
```

The dataset denotes which brand a customer consume at a time point.

From this dataset I want to create 3 variables:

a) Dummy variable to denote if Brand Type is B1 or B2. I can do this the following way:

```
d111['Brand_Type_new']=d111['Brand_Type'] 
#creating a separate column to preserve the Brand_type variable
d1111= pd.get_dummies(d111, prefix='Category_', columns=['Brand_Type'])
```

b) A dummy variable to denote if the participant consumed Brand B1 two periods ago.

[image]

Note for Participant1, the first two rows are 0 since there are no observations. The third row (for 4/3/2010) is 1, since the customer consumed B1 at time 1/27/2010 (two periods ago).

c) A variable to denote the number of times a participant has consumed the brand before (excluding the current period.

[image]

For the first row, the value is 0. The second row is 1 since the participant has consumed B1 in the previous period and so on.

Thanks a lot in advance.

This is a test data and the original data has different dates for the two participants (different number of observations for participants). I needed help how to do this when the number of dates etc is different for participants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your solution shown below for section a:

```
d111['Brand_Type_new']=d111['Brand_Type'] 
#creating a separate column to preserve the Brand_type variable
d1111= pd.get_dummies(d111, prefix='Category_', columns=['Brand_Type'])
print(d1111)

   Participant_ID      Date1      Date2 Brand_Type_new  Category__B1  \
1              P1  1/27/2010 2010-01-27             B1             1   
4              P1   3/1/2010 2010-03-01             B2             0   
2              P1   4/3/2010 2010-04-03             B2             0   
0              P1   5/6/2010 2010-05-06             B1             1   
5              P1   6/8/2010 2010-06-08             B2             0   
3              P1  7/11/2010 2010-07-11             B1             1   
7              P2  1/27/2010 2010-01-27             B2             0   
10             P2   3/1/2010 2010-03-01             B1             1   
8              P2   4/3/2010 2010-04-03             B1             1   
6              P2   5/6/2010 2010-05-06             B2             0   
11             P2   6/8/2010 2010-06-08             B1             1   
9              P2  7/11/2010 2010-07-11             B2             0   

    Category__B2  
1              0  
4              1  
2              1  
0              0  
5              1  
3              0  
7              1  
10             0  
8              0  
6              1  
11             0  
9              1
```

You can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
new_d=d1111.copy()
B1_groups=new_d.groupby('Participant_ID')['Category__B1']
new_d['B1_dummy_2periodAgo']=B1_groups.shift(2,fill_value=0)
new_d['B1_Cumulative']=B1_groups.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))
print(new_d)


   Participant_ID      Date1      Date2 Brand_Type_new  Category__B1  \
1              P1  1/27/2010 2010-01-27             B1             1   
4              P1   3/1/2010 2010-03-01             B2             0   
2              P1   4/3/2010 2010-04-03             B2             0   
0              P1   5/6/2010 2010-05-06             B1             1   
5              P1   6/8/2010 2010-06-08             B2             0   
3              P1  7/11/2010 2010-07-11             B1             1   
7              P2  1/27/2010 2010-01-27             B2             0   
10             P2   3/1/2010 2010-03-01             B1             1   
8              P2   4/3/2010 2010-04-03             B1             1   
6              P2   5/6/2010 2010-05-06             B2             0   
11             P2   6/8/2010 2010-06-08             B1             1   
9              P2  7/11/2010 2010-07-11             B2             0   

    Category__B2  B1_dummy_2periodAgo  B1_Cumulative  
1              0                    0              0  
4              1                    0              1  
2              1                    1              1  
0              0                    0              1  
5              1                    0              2  
3              0                    1              2  
7              1                    0              0  
10             0                    0              0  
8              0                    0              1  
6              1                    1              2  
11             0                    1              2  
9              1                    0              3
```